# How to connect to SQL SERVER using php?

Tags: server, php, sql

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 on Windows PC but my PHP is on Ubuntu, hosted by webfusion.

I haven't configured anything at all but I want PHP to connect to SQL Server. What drivers do I need and how can I install it?

Comment: I don't know much about it, but I think most people will tell you to take a look at PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

I think it is built in http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php I haven't had to do this before but I ran into this a while back while looking for something similar for work.

Comment: It is built in but unfortunately only works on windows platform. If your php is on linux, it throws error.